# A GET request from axios is making my html page reload to many times

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, http, axios

index.js

```
import axiosInstance from "../helpers/axiosInstanceClient.js";

function updateContent(response) {
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = response.data.Tot;
}

axiosInstance
  .get("/seller")
  .then((response) => {
    updateContent(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  });
```

axiosInstanceClient.js
this is an axiosInstance where i tried to make interceptor to make sure that the user is logged in before accessing the dashboard

```
import { showLoader, hideLoader } from "./loader.js";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age": "3600"
    }
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  showLoader();
  return config;
});
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
      hideLoader();
      return Promise.resolve(response);
  },
  (error) => {
      hideLoader();
      
    if(error.response.status === 401 && !window. location. href.includes('login.html')) {
      window.location.href = 'login.html';
    }
      return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);


export default axiosInstance;
```

I tried just to send a GET request but it ended up sending an INF number of requests that made the Page reload each time.

Comment: FYI, the `Access-Control-Allow-XXX` headers are meaningless in requests, they're only for responses.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause it to run repeatedly. You can set an XHR breakpoint in the browser, then you can see where the additional calls are coming from.

Comment: after i used XHR breakpoint found that 
 ** 'var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
   var socket = new WebSocket(address);
   socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
    if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
    else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
   };'**
this is the source of the reloading

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Axios call, that's WebSockets. When you call the WebSocket server, it returns a message saying to reload, so you reload.